# Makedate function in sqlite

Tags: sqlite

I need to create a date from the year and the day number of the year in sqlite, I have seen that for mysql there is the MAKEDATE () function, which does exactly what I need, but in sqlite it doesn't work.
How could I solve this?

For example:
I have a year 2020 and number day 20, i expected this output = '2020-04-01'

Answer (score 1):

I m not sure about where you are going to use, but  Sqlite does provide modifiers that you can use for the various date-time functions.

Check this [link](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html). It is not possible to provide the detail explanation here so I m referring to the link.

Below is one such query I prepared using those modifiers, this query calculates the date, by changing `now` to `start of year` and adding **20 days (NNN days)**,

```
SELECT DATE('now','start of year','20 days');
```

You can check this query output [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/9eecb7/6057).

So natively Sqlite supports this, but I m not sure about the application you will be using SQLite with supports this or not.